A Divergence Criteria to Series of variables between $1$ and $0$
I want to prove the equivalence of the two conditions below. If someone could help me I would appreciate very much!
$$p_1,p_2,.... \in (0,1)$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(1-p_i)=\infty\iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i=0.$$
I've tried the $\Longleftarrow$ but got stuck:
So, by the limit definition, for every $\epsilon>0$,  $\exists N$, such that for every $n>N$:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i < \epsilon.$$
Let's fix an $n$ that satisfies this condition.
For each $1 \leq i \leq n$:
$$p_i < \frac{\epsilon}{\prod_{j \neq  i}^{n}p_j}$$
so:
$$1 - p_i > 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{\prod_{j \neq  i}^{n}p_j} $$
so, summing across all $p$'s:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(1-p_i) > n - \epsilon \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{\prod_{j \neq  i}^{n}p_j}$$
Now, I could say that $\epsilon$ is "arbitrarily small" and this goes to infinity as n grows, but the denominator also goes to 0 by hypothesis, so I don't know how to proceed. The $\Longrightarrow$ I couldn't even start...

You should show your work and effort on that.

You are right, just corrected it

Use the fact $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$, we have $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(1-p_i)<\infty\iff\sum_{i=1}^\infty\log p_i\ \text{is convergent and the sum $S<0$},$$ so $$\iff\sum_{i=1}^n\log p_i=\log\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\to S<0
\iff\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\to e^S>0.$$

As a positive series, $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(1-p_i)<\infty$ or $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(1-p_i)=\infty$. As a decreasing sequences, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-p_i)\to P\in[0,1).$
